# isSelected() problems with radio buttons

Tags: java, selenium, radio-button

I have a function whose purpose is to change the state of a radio button, it looks like this:

```
public void changeRadioState(List<WebElement> radioButtons){        
    for(WebElement radioButton: radioButtons)
    {
        if (!radioButton.isSelected()){              
            radioButton.click();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, this works about 90% of the time but sometimes it will click on the non selected button and then go through the loop again and klick back on the previous one, resulting in the state to be the same after the function is run. witch to me can only mean that the selected state is not found on either of them, altho when I find the elements in the console I find them with a selected state. Anyone know why this would be happening?

Comment: Silly question why y\would you want to fire a click event on a non selected button ? .. Do you not just simply want to clear selected or select options which are not selected ?

Comment: Uhm.. because fiering a click event on a already selected button would be quite redundant :P, All the function does is changeing the radio state. It's used for my edit tests where I make use changes in my form are saved, radio states are among those things.

Comment: I'd imagine the outputs of this function would change dramatically depending on what the state of the radio buttons are.

Comment: well usually there are just 2 radio buttons and if the first is selected, then it will press the second one and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just realised since I don't want to change the state more then once I can just use a break in the if. but still a wierd problem this function caused.

```
public void changeRadioState(List<WebElement> radioButtons){        
   for(WebElement radioButton: radioButtons)
   {
       if (!radioButton.isSelected()){              
          radioButton.click();
          break;
       }
   }
}
```